# Solr proximity search scoring

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to Solr and studying the basic scoring model. I understand that basic scoring model employs Boolean to generate the document set and then uses the vector space model to score for ranking according to relevance.
What I want to know that while using Proximity searches, do the search results also gets ranked according to the vector space model after generation OR are they just scored based on the edit distance?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, VSM score is used in `org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.TFIDFSimilarity` (keep in mind, it's not a default Similarity in the recent versions of Lucene). For example, `org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity` implements something similar, but rather called [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25).

In case of proximity searches, the base class [org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) has a nested class 
 `Similarity.SimScorer` which is responsible for scoring "sloppy" queries such as `SpanQuery`, and `PhraseQuery`. Usually, there is a method calculating `sloppyFreq`, which is a function of edit distance and it's added as an additional coefficient in formula.

One of the default implementations of the `sloppyFreq` is `1.0f / (distance + 1)`, but of course it could be customized, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So solr adds this sloppyFreq score to the final VSM score of a document?